# How to allow each allowed character in given string to trigger if-statement

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I've been searching on here for a bit and nothing seems to really encapsulate my actual issue, being that I want my given string(if its characters fit my criteria) to cause different if statements. The purpose of my code is for each letter to represent a rotation of my string.

example parts['rotate'] = 'Ff'

```
allowed = ['F', 'f', 'R', 'r', 'B', 'b', 'L', 'l', 'U', 'u', 'D', 'd']

def rotated(parms):
    result = {}
    if ('cube' not in parms):
        result['status'] = 'error: cube is missing!'
    cube = list(parms['cube'])
    if ('rotate' not in parms or parms['rotate'] == ''):
        return rotateF(cube)
    if (parms['rotate'] == 'F'):
        return rotateF(cube)
    if (parms['rotate'] == 'f'):
        return rotatef(cube)
    if (parms['rotate'] != allowed):
        result['status'] = 'error: invalid rotation'
return result

def rotateF(cube):
    rotatedCube = list(cube)
    .....
    rotatedCube = ''.join(rotatedCube)
    return rotatedCube
def rotatef(cube):
    rotatedCube = list(cube)
    ......
    rotatedCube = ''.join(rotatedCube)
    return rotatedCube
```

And so currently, the return i'm getting is for 'rotate' = 'Ff' :

```
{'status': 'error: invalid rotation'}
```

My assumption is that it is because currently, my code only allows for one character at a time when I just wanted to ensure that those were the only allowed characters, not one per string.

Comment: It's difficult for me to understand what you are askin. It would help if you show a [mcve]. This should be something we can copy/paste and run ourselves without any additional errors other than what you are asking about.

Comment: On a side note, why does `rotated()` take a single `parms` parameter? It seems like this would be better written with two parameters: `def rotated(cube, rotate):`. Doing this would drastically simplify your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  Basically I see that when I input more than 1 letter into my string it simply just skips over all of the if statements straight to it thinking the input isn't allowed, when I actually want it to first run my command for 'F' and then my command for 'f'.(or whatever combination of characters I choose to input.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I do agree that it would be simpler but I am first just trying to solve these issues before refactoring.

Comment: Then you need `for letter in parms['rotate']:`.  Right?  That will work whether you give it one letter or 9.  Also note that `if` statements in Python do not use extra parentheses.  That's a habit leftover from C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your rotate function is written is to compare against exactly a specific string, but it seems like you are providing a list of rotations (in python, a string is a list of characters). Try introducing another helper function, splitting `rotated` in to something like `do_single_rotation`, and `do_all_rotations` (I'm leaving out some of the error handling and whatnot as I'm not sure exactly what your goal is for the function to return)

```py
default_rotate_str = 'F'

def do_all_rotations(parms):
    rotate_str = parms.get('rotate', default_rotate_str)
    cube = list(parms['cube'])
    for rotate_command in rotate_str:
        cube = do_single_rotation(cube, rotate_command)
    return cube

def do_single_rotation(cube, rotate_command):
    if rotate_command == 'F':
        return rotate_F(cube)
    if rotate_command == 'f';
        return rotate_f(cube)
    # .... continue
    if rotate_command == 'D':
        rotate_d(cube)
    raise ValueError("unrecognized rotate command")
```

Comment: My goal is to return the 'cube' key within my output dictionary (result={})